# django template if return True even if variable False

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am beginner in django and most probably i do something wrong.

My view :

```html
class StartPageIndexView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = UserLoginRegistrationForm()
        lorem_ipsum_text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

        print("request.user %s", request.user)
        is_logged_on = False
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            logger.error("User authenticated")
            is_logged_on = True

        context = {
            'lorem_ipsum': lorem_ipsum_text,
            'registration_form': form,
            'is_logged_on': is_logged_on,
        }
        return render(request, 'startpage/index.html', context=context)
```

my template :

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% if is_logged_on is True %}
    {% block sidebar %}
        {{ is_logged_on }}
        {% include "inc/_sidebar.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
{% block content %}
    {{ is_logged_on }}
    {{ lorem_ipsum }}
{% endblock %}
```

In browser i see this . Can you please tell me what i do wrong ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NadwK.png)

Comment: where does it return true, what makes you think that

Comment: Well l think that i have to see sidebar only in case if variable "is_logged_on" is True. But i see it even if "is_logged_on" is False . I think that this variable is False because i do output of this variable using {{ is_logged_on }}

Comment: @JohnDoe Don't put a block inside if. put if inside block.

Comment: You can set if inside block but you cannot dictate block showing a way you did try. Block extending is done prior to logic conditioning

Comment: @JohnDoe look at this [answer by Manoj Govindan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458909/14991864). Templates are **first compiled** then **rendered** causing this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks. Solved. Not knew about such requirment.